# How to explain sudden change from inverted band to normal band order of some surfaces of AFM topological insulator?

Tags: topological-insulators, topological-phase

For normal insulator, as we known, its bulk band is inverted and outside it is the air or vacuum which is normal insulator with band in normal order. **So to transit from bulk to outside, the band need to change from inverted order to normal order, which means there must be a gapless state between them.** And we know this is surface state.

But for AFM TI, due to magnetism, some surfaces are not protected by time-reversal and S symmetry so it's gapped. But now, **when transit from bulk to outside, the band is still inverted till the surface, and suddenly becomes to normal order in vacuum.** This is in contrast with previous argument.

So is there a good explanation of this?